# Kubernetes 1.5.4 Kube DNS Getting Deleted

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

When I run the deployment for Kubedns it launches successfully however, at exactly after 8 minutes of uptime, it is deleted. When it is running it works fine in resolving dns requests.  Has anyone else experienced this?  I'm starting to see this with other random deployments.

Kubernetes version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.4", GitCommit:"7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-07T23:53:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.4", GitCommit:"7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-07T23:34:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Environment:
Centos 7

Kernel
Linux at4d-lvk8s01 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 12 15:04:24 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Log Messages**

After deploying Kubedns:

Apr 20 13:09:33 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:09:33.571733     912 event.go:217] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Deployment", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-dns", UID:"98ad2b69-25ca-11e7-afbe-90b8d0f6559c", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"262626", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'ScalingReplicaSet' Scaled up replica set kube-dns-3777016094 to 1
Apr 20 13:09:33 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:09:33.576730     912 replica_set.go:479] Too few "kube-system"/"kube-dns-3777016094" replicas, need 1, creating 1
Apr 20 13:09:33 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:09:33.625987     912 deployment_controller.go:298] Error syncing deployment kube-system/kube-dns: Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.extensions "kube-dns": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
Apr 20 13:09:33 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:09:33.656784     912 event.go:217] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"ReplicaSet", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-dns-3777016094", UID:"98b57f0f-25ca-11e7-afbe-90b8d0f6559c", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"262627", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'SuccessfulCreate' Created pod: kube-dns-3777016094-9jt36
Apr 20 13:09:33 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:09:33.702938     912 deployment_controller.go:298] Error syncing deployment kube-system/kube-dns: Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.extensions "kube-dns": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
Apr 20 13:10:03 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: W0420 13:10:03.960803     912 reflector.go:319] pkg/controller/garbagecollector/garbagecollector.go:768: watch of  ended with: 401: The event in requested index is outdated and cleared (the requested history has been cleared [261724/260681]) [262723]

Immediately before Kubedns is deleted:

Apr 20 13:17:49 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:17:49.528874     912 replica_set.go:512] Too many "kube-system"/"kube-dns-3777016094" replicas, need 0, deleting 1
Apr 20 13:17:49 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:17:49.528973     912 controller_utils.go:523] Controller kube-dns-3777016094 deleting pod kube-system/kube-dns-3777016094-9jt36
Apr 20 13:17:49 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:17:49.532985     912 event.go:217] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"Deployment", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-dns", UID:"98ad2b69-25ca-11e7-afbe-90b8d0f6559c", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"263765", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'ScalingReplicaSet' Scaled down replica set kube-dns-3777016094 to 0
Apr 20 13:17:49 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:17:49.600483     912 deployment_controller.go:298] Error syncing deployment kube-system/kube-dns: Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.extensions "kube-dns": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
Apr 20 13:17:49 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:17:49.623854     912 event.go:217] Event(api.ObjectReference{Kind:"ReplicaSet", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-dns-3777016094", UID:"98b57f0f-25ca-11e7-afbe-90b8d0f6559c", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"263766", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'SuccessfulDelete' Deleted pod: kube-dns-3777016094-9jt36
Apr 20 13:17:52 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:17:52.642886     912 garbagecollector.go:761] none of object [v1/Pod, namespace: kube-system, name: kube-dns-3777016094-9jt36, uid: 98d5d128-25ca-11e7-afbe-90b8d0f6559c]'s owners exist any more, will garbage collect it
Apr 20 13:17:52 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: I0420 13:17:52.665171     912 deployment_controller.go:322] Deployment has been deleted kube-system/kube-dns
Apr 20 13:18:04 acme-lvk8s01 kube-controller-manager[912]: W0420 13:18:04.972362     912 reflector.go:319] pkg/controller/garbagecollector/garbagecollector.go:768: watch of  ended with: 401: The event in requested index is outdated and cleared (the requested history has been cleared [262818/262725]) [263817]

Answer (score 0):

Had to comment out the following line in my deployment file.

kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"

Answer (score 0):

There is a serivce called kube-addons,I guess you don't start it.
Try this to know the service status：

> systemctl status kube-addons.service

if status is stop,just start it and problems will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

After I commented out the following line the deployment was stable.

kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"